# Loop in powershell

Tags: powershell

Hello Guys need some help, tips with script:

```
$path = ".\" # path do txt
$server = "server"  # server.txt
$paczki = ".\paczki\"
$missingi = "$path\$server.txt"  
$plik = get-content $missingi

foreach ($j in $plik) {
    Write-Output "1"
    $wynik = Get-ChildItem "$paczki" | ? {$_.name -match "$j"} 
    if ($wynik -eq $null) {
        # Write-Host $i 
    }
    else {  
        Write-Output "2"
        Write-Host $wynik "znaleziono"   
        Copy-Item $paczki\$wynik  -Destination \\$server\c$\temp\ -force 
    }
}

#### BAT GENERATOR #####
Write-Output "3"
#  & .\bat_generator.ps1  

$zapis = "$path\test.bat" 
"pushd %~dp0" > $zapis 
$nazwa = Get-ChildItem  "\\$server\c$\temp\" | select name 

foreach ($i in $nazwa) {
    $text = $i.name + " /norestart /quiet" 
    $text >> $zapis
}
"ppd0" >> $zapis # dodaj ppd0

move-item -path .\test.bat -destination \\$server\c$\temp\ -Force # skopiuj .bat na server
```

At first I create file with name of server, for example `server.txt` in this server we have list of KBs. Scripts searching in folder `paczki` that KB exist if yes copying this in server and create .bat

I would like do add automatically searching all .txt files eg `server.txt`, & `server1.txt` and use it in loop, I thought about something like that:

```
$pliki_txt= Get-ChildItem $path -Filter "*.txt" |  % {$_.BaseName}
```

and put it in loop but its not really working, I try to add loop in this place:

```
for ($i in pliki_txt)
    $path = ".\" # path do txt
     $server="server"  # server.txt
    $pliki_txt= Get-ChildItem $path -Filter "*.txt" |  % {$_.BaseName}
            (....)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any easier way? Script is only working when I put manually set `$server` like `$server="serwer"`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a [mcve] of your code plus all error messages that code is giving you. Currently all I see is code bits that don't really match each other with no indication as to how *exactly* the code is "not really working".

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$path = ".\"

Get-ChildItem $path -Filter *.txt |  %{ 
    $content = Get-content $_.FullName
    Foreach($server in $content){
        write-host $server
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got that right, the issue here is that you're not putting the lines in the right order.

From your original code I would change the following

```
$path = ".\" # path do txt
$server = "server"  # server.txt
$paczki = ".\paczki\"
# $missingi = "$path\$server.txt"  
$missingi = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter server*.txt | Select -ExpandProperty Name
foreach ($m in $missingi) {
    $plik = get-content $m
    ( ... )
}
```

That way you'll check every server*.txt file in that path and process it accordingly.

Or you could even turn it into a parameterized script like this

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]$path,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]$pattern,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]$packzi
)
$missingi = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter *.txt | Select -ExpandProperty | Select-String "$pattern"
foreach ($m in $missingi) {
    $plik = get-content $m
    foreach ($j in $plik) {
        Write-Output "1"
        $wynik = Get-ChildItem "$paczki" | ? {$_.name -match "$j"} 
        if ($wynik -eq $null) {
            # Write-Host $i 
        }
        else {  
            Write-Output "2"
            Write-Host $wynik "znaleziono"   
            Copy-Item $paczki\$wynik  -Destination \\$server\c$\temp\ -force 
        }
    }

    #### BAT GENERATOR #####
    Write-Output "3"
    #  & .\bat_generator.ps1  

    $zapis = "$path\test.bat" 
    "pushd %~dp0" > $zapis 
    $nazwa = Get-ChildItem  "\\$server\c$\temp\" | select name 

    foreach ($i in $nazwa) {
        $text = $i.name + " /norestart /quiet" 
        $text >> $zapis
    }
    "ppd0" >> $zapis # dodaj ppd0

    move-item -path .\test.bat -destination \\$server\c$\temp\ -Force # skopiuj .bat na server
}
```

Then you would run it like this:

```
.\YourScript.ps1 -path ".\" -pattern "server" -packzi ".\packzi\"
```

That will give you more flexibility if you want to change the source path, the name pattern or the search patch.

I hope this helps.